# The difference between "lots of" and "much"

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between *much* and *lots of* to express large quantity of uncountable noun.

NOAD defines *lots* as:

> a great deal; much

and defines *much* as:

> to a great extent; a great deal

so it's obvious the two can be used as synonyms. But are there any differences?

Comment: The semantic similarities are obvious, but there are some grammatical differences, for example "much" is incompatible with count singular nouns (*much cars), while "lots of" can be used with both count and non-count nouns ("lots of cars" / "lots of money").

Answer (score 4):

I think the overall meaning is pretty much the same, but there is a slight difference in tone: *lots of* has a more informal tone that might work well on a playground or in a valentine, but *much* might be a good substitute for a campaign speech or technical paper.

> We had lots of trouble getting the experiment to work.
>   We had much trouble getting the experiment to work.

I think the bottom version would sound better in a technical paper. However, sometimes you can make the noun countable, and use *many* instead of *much*. For example:

> We encountered many problems getting the experiment to work.

It also depends on the context. Sometimes you can't simply substitute one for the other. For example:

> Add lots of chili powder if you like it spicy.
>   Add much chili powder if you like it spicy.

In that example, I prefer the top sentence (the "lots of" version). However, if we switch to the negative, things might change:

> Don't add lots of chili powder unless you like it spicy.
>   Don't add too much chili powder unless you like it spicy.

In that example, I prefer the bottom sentence, with a *too* added before *much*.

As for picking the best wording, I'm not sure if there's a general guideline that can be followed. There are many complicating factors, so this is is one of those areas where you need to rely on intuition, style, context, and experience.

Comment: Your examples are perfect! Have my upvote :)